# function to search database for keywords

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

trying to get functionality to search a mysql database for keywords using javascript, running into problems with how to execute the commands in js and how to insert the keywords from an input box to the mysql query.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script> function mysqlList(){

var keyword = document.getElementById('keyword').value;


var mysql = require('mysql');


var connection = mysql.createConnection(
{
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'xxxxxx',
password : 'xxxxxx',
database : 'joblist',
}
);

connection.connect();


var queryString = 'SELECT name, trello FROM graduates WHERE (name LIKE '%keyword%'    OR trello LIKE '%keyword%');

connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
if (err) throw err;

for (var i in rows) {
var console = console.log('name: ', rows[i].name, '|',  'trello: ', rows[i].trello);
}
});

connection.end(); 
};

window.console = {
log: function(str){
var node = document.createElement("div");
node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
document.getElementById("myLog").appendChild(node);
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="onload();">
<input type="text" name="enter" class="enter" value="" id="keyword"/>

<button onclick="mysqlList()">run query</button>



<p id="myLog"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

this is non functional at the moment, but even if anyone could point me in the direction of some good tutorials I would appreciate it.

thanks!

Comment: `this is non functional at the moment` really? why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: why do you have html in what is clearly a nodejs script?

Comment: This doesn't work because it isn't server side. You are trying to execute server side code, client side.

Comment: well I'm trying to build it into a node app eventually, like I had some code that could return all content in a table, but I need it to run in browser and use keyword input.

Comment: Code meant for the server, must be executed on the server. Since MySQL is server side, it must be played with there.

Comment: @Derek okay okay so how would I do this client side? I'm not sure what I should be searching for, if you know any good tutorials that'd be great.

Comment: You can't do this client side without having an ajax request to something server side that returns the data you want

Comment: @Derek oh so that becomes even more confusing. is this project going to be super challenging? it seems simple in concept, but I'm not sure of how to put it into action.

Comment: @hm from where you are, yeah most likely. I suggest starting with some NodeJS basic tutorials. Also, look into packages like `hapi.js` or `expressjs`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

First: `require()` is specific to NodeJS. It is not available in the browser. Some of the modules which can be loaded with it are available in the browser, but `mysql` is not.

Second, and related: You can't connect to a MySQL database directly from a web browser. Javascript running in a browser can only make HTTP connections to web servers, and even then only on a limited basis.

You need to implement an API on the server -- possibly using Node, possibly something else -- to perform a search. Then you can use the [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) browser API -- or something based on it, like [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) in jQuery -- to call that API.